# Houghlines2 with pixelated line

Tags: opencv, line, detection, hough-transform

I am trying to detect a line with houghlines2, but my line is pixelated, and therefore houghlines2 cannot recognize it as a line. What happens is I detect part of the line, but not the full line - as illustrated with the red lines filling more and more of the line

[image]

I have tried to blur the line a bit, but so far no luck.

Code: http://pastebin.com/zmsCFucM

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I have worked with canny with no luck either.

**EDIT**

When I measure then line in paint, let's say it's 30. (I do this by sqrt(lengthx^2 + lengthy^2)). Then the minLength in houghlines2 probalistic has to be waaaay shorter. I think this is my problem, and I have no idea why it has to be way shorter. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to modify rho and theta resolution. Set rho at 2, instead of 1, and theta at PI/90.

Comment: That did not help unfortunately

Comment: This helps, and I can detect the line. But it is a problem with dashed lines

Comment: dashed lines have less pixels, so you have to lower the threshold. And it would be a good idea to learn about how Hough works. Try `wiki hough` and read carefully.

Comment: Hi Vasile. I almost have it working. I am having a problem though. When I take an ROI of the image, then it does not match anymore, eventhough it contains the line. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Probably you forgot to convert resulting points from ROI to the original image.

Comment: Vasile could you write an answer please?
I have read the hough transform on wiki, but I still have a hard time understanding what rho and theta defines in the probalistic hough transform.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have that time :) Try a bit harder, look at the code in OpenCV, and in a few days you should be ready. Trying to understand it in half an hour is futile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to downscale your image... Thanks to that, your line will be One pixel width !
Theoretically we can found a set of Hough transform parameters which will detect your lines.

You can try to replace CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC by CV_HOUGH_MULTI_SCALE in your code, that will try to find lines at different scale.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on what I gathered from your question.

so it is detecting two lines instead of a single one, right? 
  Of the two detected (use the probabilistic flag), compare the four sets of line end-points (each line will have two). There will be two points between which the distance will be a minimum. Merge these two to get three points. Now the way would be to consider the other two points and draw a line.

OR Use the line fitting function (OpenCV has one) on the four end-points you get from Hough Line detection. The cvFitLine() returns a vector representation of the line - no end points. So clip that fitted line at co-ordinates of the end-points of hough lines that are farthest away from each other.

Comment: It is so pixelated that it does not find any lines. I have to blur it before to find any lines at all